# How to fix not showing any data using while loop in php

Tags: php, mysql, vb.net, hosting

I am rather new in PHP and MYSQL, I am trying to fetch all the rows in the database which have not been updated (or received) in the status column.

This code snippet works perfectly when fetching single row values. When trying to insert a while loop in the code. It shows blank response when using echo.

The is no error message shown or even an "x" in the editor when saving. Just a blank screen when url is called and tested using browser. I am using file manager in Hostinger for my php files and mysql database.

```php
// array for JSON response
$response = array();

try {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Complaints where status=''";

    if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
        if (mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) > 0) {
            $response["success"] = 1;
            $response["message"] = "Request successfully created.";

            $row = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($conn, $sql));

            $photo = $row['id'];
            $name = $row['name'];
            $sin = $row['sin'];
            $cp_no = $row['cp_no'];
            $complaint = $row['complaint'];
            $landmark = $row['landmark'];

            $response["success"] = 1;
            $response["name"] = $name;
            $response["id"] = $photo;
            $response["sin"] = $sin;
            $response["cp_no"] = $cp_no;
            $response["complaint"] = $complaint;
            $response["landmark"] = $landmark;
        } else {
            //no items found
            $response["success"] = 0;
            $response["message"] = "No items found.";
        }

        echo json_encode($response);
        mysqli_close($conn);
    } else {
        //failed to fetch
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Oops! an Error occured.";

        //echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
    mysqli_close($conn);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "exception";
    // failed to fetch
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = 'message: ' . $e->getMessage();

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
}
```

This is code of what I have tried so far

```php
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($conn, $sql))) {
    $photo = $row['id'];
    $name = $row['name'];

    $response["names"] = $name;
    $response["data"] = $photo;

    // $response[$i]=$row;
}
```

The data fetched from the database would then be converted to json format.

hich will then be parsed on VB.net
this code also works fine on single row values

**VB.NET CODE**

```
    Dim request As HttpWebRequest
    Dim response As HttpWebResponse = Nothing
    Dim reader As StreamReader

    request = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create("http://u969542451.hostingerapp.com/Get_Data.php"), HttpWebRequest)

    response = DirectCast(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
    reader = New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())

    Dim rawresp As String
    rawresp = reader.ReadToEnd()
    TextBox2.Text = rawresp.ToString
    MsgBox(rawresp.ToString)

    Dim jsonResulttodict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Dictionary(Of String, Object))(rawresp)
    Dim dataItem = jsonResulttodict.Item("id")
    Dim nameItem = jsonResulttodict.Item("name")
    Dim SINItem = jsonResulttodict.Item("sin")
    Dim cpItem = jsonResulttodict.Item("cp_no")
    Dim compItem = jsonResulttodict.Item("complaint")
    Dim LMItem = jsonResulttodict.Item("landmark")
    Dim typeItem = "COMPLAINT"

    dgvSearch.Rows.Add(SINItem, nameItem, dataItem, cpItem, compItem, LMItem, typeItem)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you please try like this

```
try {
    $response = array();
    $i=0;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Complaints where status=''";
    $data = mysqli_query($conn, $sql)
    if (mysqli_num_rows($data) > 0) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data)) {
            $photo = $row['id'];
            $name = $row['name'];

            $response[$i]["names"] = $name;
            $response[$i]["data"] = $photo;
            $i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Php now works, {"success":1,"message":"Request successfully created.","0":{"names":"name here","data":"2"},"1":{"names":"name here","data":"3"}}

Comment: do you also know what needs to be fixed in the .net code to parse array instead of 1 row only

Comment: Sorry for .net I don't know you can check my code and follow that step.

Comment: it looks like the reponse now is an object containing 2 objects (per row), I can parse 1 object at a time, what needs to be changed so I can split them first

Comment: are you not able to get same response like php or something else I am not getting your point

Comment: okay I "tweaked" your example code and got what I needed. thanks for helping